# Makefile won't check if updated, and just compiles anyway

Tags: makefile

My makefile will not check if there has been any updates and just compiles if it has more than a single source file added in. It works fine with just a single source file.

It seems that it's any source file that's not listed as the first one will always be recompiled and linked.

```
SOURCES=myclass.cpp mylock.cpp
EXECUTABLE=locktest
LIBRARIES=-pthread
CFLAGS=-Wall
CXX=g++
DIR=host/
EXE=$(EXECUTABLE)

OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(DIR)%.o)

$(EXE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LIBRARIES)

$(DIR)%.o: %.cpp $(DIR)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 

$(DIR):
    @mkdir $(DIR)

clean: 
    @rm $(OBJECTS) $(EXE)
    @rmdir $(DIR)
```

Output shows problem:

```
stud@pc:~/Desktop/Locktest$ make
g++ -Wall -c myclass.cpp -o host/myclass.o 
g++ -Wall -c mylock.cpp -o host/mylock.o 
g++ -o locktest host/myclass.o host/mylock.o -pthread
stud@pc:~/Desktop/Locktest$ make
g++ -Wall -c myclass.cpp -o host/myclass.o 
g++ -o locktest host/myclass.o host/mylock.o -pthread
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @lijat points out, when you build an object in `$(DIR)`, the operating system updates the modification time of the directory, so that in this rule:

```
$(DIR)%.o: %.cpp $(DIR)
    ...
```

the prerequisite `$(DIR)` will always appear to be newer than any target except the last target built.

If your version of Make is recent enough, you can get past this by making `$(DIR)` an [order-only prerequisite](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types):

```
$(DIR)%.o: %.cpp | $(DIR)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Does the filesystem update the modified time on the DIR directory when the compiler writes an .o file there

$(DIR)%.o: %.cpp $(DIR)

ensures that all .o files will be recompiled if anything updates the modified time of that directory.